# Does YouTube block scheme 'ms-appx-web' when embed video in metro app using YouTube iframe API?

Tags: iframe, microsoft-metro, youtube-api

Couple months ago, I embed YouTube video in my metro app using YouTube iframe API. I use 'ms-appx-web' to load a page in an iframe:

```
<iframe src="ms-appx-web:///youtubeplayer.html"></iframe>
```

and in the page youtubeplayer.html, I import YouTube API:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

and then create a YT player:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: 390,
                width: 640,
                'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo',
                playerVars: {
                    showinfo: 1,
                    modestbranding: 0
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                }
            });
        }
```

At first, it works well. But since couple days ago, I find that YouTube player's events('onPlayerReady', 'onPlayerStateChange' etc.) are not fired. 
Then I try put the page youtubeplayer.html to a remote web server, the all events go well again.
I do not why this happens. Because if load a page using 'ms-appx-web', the page is running in remote content, too, just like it is on a remote web server. So I want to know if YouTube  block the scheme 'ms-appx-web' of MS recently.